# HTML CSS JS | Adding +1 to z-index value once a certain element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, z-index

Hello guys i've been having a problem about z-index and jquery. What i've been trying to do is a script that works with clicks and adds +1 to the z-index of the div to make it always on top.

Here is the JS AND MARKUP

```
function bringtotop() {
  document.getElementById('bringtotop')[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('bringtotop')[0].style.zIndex = "z";
  "z++";

}



<div class="location_marker flora_sort" id="raiberica_location" onclick="bringtotop();" style="margin-top: 20.2%; margin-left: 20.2%;">
<img src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/typicons/svg/location.svg" width="35px"></img>
</div>


<div id="bringtotop raiberica" class="hiddenDivs">
<div class="image_placeholder">
<div class="image_placeholder_overlay"></div>
<img src="" width="460"></img>
<div class="div_close" onclick="showHiddenDiv('raiberica');">✖</div>
</div>
<div class="species_content">
<h1>Rã Ibérica</h1> <span>(Rana ibérica)</span>
<p><b>Categoria:</b> Anfíbios</p>
<p><b>Descrição:</b>A rã ibérica é um anfíbio sem cauda, de dimensão pequena (máximo comprimento 5,5cm) com olhos grandes e com pupila horizontal elíptica destacam-se no seu focinho pontiagudo, onde são pouco visíveis os seus pequenos tímpanos.

De pele lisa com pequenas grânulos na região dorsal, não dispõe de sacos vocais nem glândulas.</p>
</div>
</div>  



<div id="tritaoventrelaranja" class="hiddenDivs">
<div class="image_placeholder">
<div class="image_placeholder_overlay"></div>
<img src="" width="460"></img>
<div class="div_close" onclick="showHiddenDiv('tritaoventrelaranja');">✖</div>
</div>
<div class="species_content">
<h1>Tritão ventre laranja </h1> <span>(Lissontriton boscai)</span>
<p><b>Categoria:</b> Anfíbios</p>
<p><b>Descrição:</b>Também conhecido por Tritão ibérico, dado tratar-se de uma espécie endémica da Península ibérica. Uma das suas características distintivas é o ventre de cor de laranja realçado pelo facto de ter um dorso acastanhado com pintas pretas, em especial os machos.

Esta característica é utilizada pelo tritão quando se sente ameaçado, dado que se arqueia exibindo o ventre laranja, alertando os seus predadores para um grau de toxicidade que não tem.

Um dos aspetos mais curiosos desta espécie é a complexa dança nupcial que os machos executam para atrair as fêmeas. Pequeno com cabeça arredondada, os seus olhos são pequenos e estão em posição lateral. Ao longo do seu ciclo de vida, o Tritão passa a sua época de reprodução em meio aquático após o qual vive em meio terrestre.

A sua alimentação é baseada em invertebrados aquáticos de pequenas dimensões como larvas de insetos durante a sua permanência em meio aquático, posteriormente na sua passagem para o meio terrestre a base de alimentação são os invertebrados como minhocas.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ncvLun3d/

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code is setting the zIndex to the string "z", which doesn't mean anything as a z-index. If you want to assign a value to a variable, the name of the variable must be to the left of the equal sign, and the value you're assigning must be on the right.

So let's look at how we can change your code to do this:

```
function bringtotop() {
  document.getElementById('bringtotop')[0].style.display = "block";
  var z = document.getElementById('bringtotop')[0].style.zIndex; // store zIndex to variable `z`
  document.getElementById('bringtotop')[0].style.zIndex = z++; // increment z and assign the element's z-index to it

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but its still giving me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: Do you have everything spelled correctly? It sounds like it wasn't able to find an element with the exact ID you typed in.

Comment: Yes, i got this error now. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

For fixing above error, need to change below things,

1. Remove Double ID's
   As we can specify only one ID at a time for ID attribute.

   Remove one of the ID from DIV tag
2. Use below Updated function

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            var z = document.getElementById('bringtotop').style.zIndex;
            function bringtotop() {
                document.getElementById('bringtotop').children[0].style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('bringtotop').children[0].style.zIndex = z;
                z = Number(z) + 1;
            }
        </script>
```

3. Add z-index property inline.
   I am not sure about this. i tried to get z-index property from element which is assign in CSS but its giving me error But if you assign style inline its returning z-index value correctly.

Comment: This code also returns me these errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(anonymous function) @ (index):530
8(index):532 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null